# Is there a method to expand a 1D numpy array of 2D numpy arrays into a 3D numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, reshape, shapes

I currently have a 1D numpy array `arr` of shape `(2620,)` containing elements of 2D numpy arrays of shape `(298, 12)`. Is there a method to create a 3D numpy array with the same elements and shape `(2620, 298, 12)`? I'm new to numpy and preprocessing data for a CNN and need 3D array for proper input dimensions.

In the original code, calling `arr.shape` returns `(2620,)` when it should return `(2620, 298, 12)`. Also, I am not able to use the command `arr.reshape` because ndarray is believe to only have 2620 values of type `object`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ut can be donewith broadcasting. Just specify what value is expected for element at outarr[i,j,k] in relation to arr. Is it outarr[i,j,k]==arr[i]?

Comment: `np.stack(arr)` should work if all elements of `arr` have the same shape.  But it will throw an error if they differ.  And the fact `arr` is 1d containing arrays, suggests they probably do differ.  In that case you are stuck - unless you can identify which arrays differ in shape.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks so much! Tried `np.stack(arr)` and it threw an error, so I ran a for loop and found that some arrays differed in shape. Iterated them out and `np.asarray(arr)` returned the proper shape.